# declare default value for variables in ampl

Tags: ampl

Now I have variable set x in my ampl model, and I want to define a default value for each x.

```
set N := 1..10;
var x {i in N} default 0;
```

If I build the model like this, the initial value of all x would be set as 0. How can I set different value for each x, like [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change some parts of x to a non-default value, this is easy to do. For example:

```
var x{i in N} default 0;
let{i in 6..10} x[i] := 1;
```

I'm not aware of any way to have more than one *default* value for different elements of a var.